# Windows Command Copy all files recursively to a Main Folder

Tags: windows, command-line, file-management

I was wondering if there is a quick and dirty command that can copy all files in a directory and it's subdirectory to another folder. The destination folder will have no subdirectories just all the source files.

Also as an added bit of fun, in case there is a file name conflict, not to overwrite but to rename the destination file with something unique, maybe append _1 to the filename?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will copy the files and prompt if there is a filename conflict.

The third party tool `XXcopy` has the ability to flatten a directory tree and handle filename conflicts.

```
@echo off
for /r "d:\folder" %%a in (*) do copy "%%a" "E:\target folder"
```

Comment: %%a was unexpected at this time.

Comment: @RobE The `@echo off` is a clue that it is a batch file.

Answer (score 1):

To copy for instance all files from the current folder and its sub directories to the parent folder of the current folder you can use:

```
for /r . %a in (*) do copy %a ..
```